# Is the wcf federated security token a session token or reusable?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, session, wcf-security

I have been reading up a bit on federated security and WCF and have a question about the lifetime of the token issued by the Security Token Service (STS).

Is the security token for the specific session being initiated with the server, or can it be reused in multiple sessions?

My goal is to be able to invalidate all security tokens issued by the STS by closing all open sessions and forcing reauthentication.  I am concerned that a malicous user could just reuse a token already issued.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The SecurityToken returned from the STS expires after 1 hour (default). You can reuse it in multiple sessions using the following code.

```
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
```

But you must of course cache the token somewhere for this to happen. If you use the standard CreateChannel() method I belive the token will be requested from the STS every time.